# Čech representatives for Chern classes in holomorphic Deligne cohomology

Tags: complex-geometry, chern-classes, cech-cohomology

Let $X$ be a complex-analytic manifold with "nice" (e.g. Stein) cover $\mathcal{U}=\{U_\alpha\}$, and $E$ a holomorphic vector bundle on $X$ defined by transition functions $\{g_{\alpha\beta}\}$.
For ease of notation, define
$$
  \omega_{\alpha\beta} = g_{\alpha\beta}^{-1}\mathrm{d}g_{\alpha\beta}
$$
which gives an endomorphism-valued $1$-form.

There is an explicit way of expressing the Chern classes of $E$ in de Rham cohomology in terms of the transition functions.

1. The first Chern class is simple: $\operatorname{tr}\omega_{\alpha\beta}$ is a degree $(1,1)$ element in the Čech–de Rham bicomplex that is both Čech and de Rham closed, and thus defines an element in degree 2 de Rham cohomology, which can be shown to be exactly the first Chern class.
2. For the second Chern class, we define a degree $(2,2)$ element $c_{2,2}$ in the Čech–de Rham bicomplex by
   $$
     c_{2,2}=\operatorname{tr}\big(\omega_{\alpha\beta}(\omega_{\alpha\gamma}-\omega_{\alpha\beta})\big)
   $$
   which is Čech closed, but not de Rham closed.
   But we can find a degree $(1,3)$ element whose Čech differential is exactly the de Rham differential of $c_{2,2}$, and finally a degree $(0,4)$ element, all of which together give a closed element in the total complex.
   This can be shown to be exactly the second Chern class.

And so on.

Note that this Čech representative for the first Chern class actually gives a closed element inside the Čech–*Deligne* bicomplex, and thus defines a first Chern class in (holomorphic) *Deligne* cohomology (it is exactly $\mathrm{d}\log g_{\alpha\beta}$).
However, the Čech representative described above for the second Chern class does not give a closed element in the Čech–Deligne complex.

**Question.**
*Has anybody written down explicit calculation of Čech representatives for Chern classes in holomorphic Deligne cohomology (purely in terms of the transition functions) somewhere? Even just for the second Chern class?*

**Non-answer.**
I am aware of the paper "Čech Cocycles for Characteristic Classes" by Brylinski and McLaughlin, which claims to do exactly this, but there are a few key details missing that they either claim are trivial or just simply do not discuss.
They give the proof for Pontryagin classes, and say that the proof for the holomorphic Chern classes are exactly the same as the smooth argument, but their proof constructs an element of $\mathrm{H}^{2p}(X,\mathbb{Z}(2p))$, whereas *holomorphic* Chern classes should live instead in $\mathrm{H}^{2p}(X,\mathbb{Z}(p))$.
I think (reading the introduction more carefully) that they are indeed only claiming to have constructed classes in *smooth* Deligne cohomology, even for holomorphic bundles.
Furthermore, they don't write down an explicit example for the holomorphic case, and I am unable to follow their construction through myself.
So I guess I would also be happy to know that (a) this degree issue can be resolved somehow, and (b) one can explictly mirror their proof and write down representatives for the second Chern class.

Comment: I am tempted to appeal to [Cunningham's law](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Cunningham%27s_Law) and answer this question saying "no, nobody has written this down because I can't find any examples"... maybe in a few months